# QtCreator Thinks Qt5 QMake installation is Invalid when setup from Yocto SDK Build

Tags: linux, qt5, qt-creator, yocto, qt5.6

I successfully built and booted the Texas Instruments Processor SDK for the BeagleBone X15 using Yocto with the following command:

```
MACHINE=beagle-x15 bitbake -c populate_sdk arago-core-tisdk-image
```

Now I installed the Yocto SDK on the Ubuntu Host machine so that I can use QtCreator to CrossCompile and deploy from Ubuntu.

I setup the kit, but Yocto believes the Qt Installation is invalid ( please see the following screenshots ):

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to source the environment-setup file prior to launching qtcreator:

```
[linux-devkit]:/usr/local/arago-2016.12> ls
environment-setup  site-config-armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi  sysroots  version-armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi
[linux-devkit]:/usr/local/arago-2016.12> pwd
/usr/local/arago-2016.12
```